# Forcing javascript on to a server

Tags: javascript, server

this might be on the edge, but the purpose is not illegal.

I want to edit a javascript on a server and feed it to the server with a change. Is this possible? To either edit it within the server and run it. Or download the script and run it to the server again. Note that I do not have admin access to the server.

Comment: Welcome to the community, your question is too broad without enough information about the server, the connection or anything. The title is not indicative of your purpose too. Edit your question and add some more information so that we can understand your issue and help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really do that without being illegal. There is a reason probably that you dont have admin access. And not having permission from the admin and doing it is also illegal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing some things here.

JavaScript is to be executed in the user's web browser. You can change the JavaScript in your browser as much as you like (with your browsers developer tools or alike) - but this will not have any effect on the server or other users.

If you would manage to change the JavaScript for ALL users, this would be a pretty critical vulnerability.

Comment: Unless the server is running server-side JavaScript via Node.js or something. Not really enough in the question to be sure.